# Как не позволять клавиатуре закрыться при нажатии на кнопку назад или OK?

Tags: android, android-edittext, клавиатура

Как не позволять клавиатуре закрыться, при нажатии на кнопку назад или OK ?

Я пробовал следующее действие:

```
EditText yourEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed);
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

с данными вариантами:

1. `imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);`
2. `imm.toggleSoftInputFromWindow( yourEditText.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);`
3. `imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);`

Comment: зачем нужна клавиатура после `Ok` и `Back`? Просто интересно. Пользователь ведь сделал/не сделал что хотел. Этими действиями он явно на это указывает.

Comment: Мне нужно чтоб кнопка Back просто сразу же возвращала на предыдущее activity

Comment: Переопределите метод `onBackPressed()` в активити.

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает

Comment: покажите как вы его переопределили.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно, чтобы при нажатии кнопки "*Назад*" был совершен переход в предыдущее активити и на экране осталась клавиатура. То проще всего в `onResume` этого предыдущего активити заново показать клавиатуру.

```
EditText editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(editText, 0);
editText.requestFocus();
```

А чтобы не нажимать кнопку "*Назад*" дважды, переопределите `onBackPressed`, чтобы почистить стек активностей и запустить нужную активность через интент.